# Using variable from AsyncTask in main code

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

### What I want

I'm determining whether or not a user is in my database.

To do that, I look at the JSON response from my webpage. This is determined in the inner-class `HasUser` which `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`.

It's a running a background process to find the user.

I want to get the result of that back in my main method. So the background process should look for the user, and then a `boolean` back in my main method should be `true` if the user was found.

### What I've done

I have added a method to the `HasUser` class called `hasUser()` which returns whether or not the user was found (as a boolean). The class has an instance variable called `found` which is assigned in the `onPostExecute` method.

So in my main method, I execute the background process, then assign the boolean value of whether or not the user was found to be `hasUser.hasUser()`. It's like this:

```
private class HasUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    boolean found = false;

    String user;
    public HasUser(String user) { this.user = user; }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        // return the JSON string response from webpage
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            // JSON stuff

            if (/*success == 0*/) { // user not found
                found = false;
            } else { // found user
                found = true;
            }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    public boolean hasUser() {
        return found;
    }

    @Override protected void onPreExecute() { }
    @Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) { }
}
```

And then in my main method, I attempt to get the appropriate result:

```
public void logIn() {
    HasUser hasUser = new HasUser("username");
    hasUser.execute();
    boolean found = hasUser.hasUser();
}
```

### Problem

Even when the user is correctly found (verified by toasting the success message), the `found` variable in `logIn()` will always be false because it is assigned before the background process is complete.

Is there any way I can make sure the background process is complete *before* I retrieve the variable from it (I know this is contrary to the meaning of the background process)? Or how else can I achieve this? I want a `boolean` back in my main method to be the proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a listener interface to pass back the result, implement your `AsyncTask` like this:

```
public class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public interface TaskListener {
        public void onFinished(boolean success);
    }

    private final TaskListener listener;

    private ExampleTask(TaskListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        boolean result = doWork();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(this.listener != null) {
            this.listener.onFinished(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
ExampleTask task = new ExampleTask(new ExampleTask.TaskListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFinished(boolean success) {
        // Do whatever you want with the result
    }
});
task.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `AsyncTask` is asynchronous that onPostExecute is called when the background thread is done but you can make the `AsyncTask` synchronous by using the `get` method after you execute it but it will wait for your AsyncTask to be done before executing the next line(causes lag bad idea).

if you dont want your `AsyncTask` synchronous with your Main thread.

what you need is to create a CallBack method(`interface`) that implements in your activity main. then pass the reference of the `interface` in your `HasUser` constructor and pass the boolean value in the interface method from your on `onPostExecute`.